# Convert image in KMZ to polygon

Tags: vectorization, kmz

I have a KMZ file that contains several image overlays (RF coverage plots).

I would like to convert the image overlays to polygons to decrease loading time in Google Maps.

Currently I'm tracing a rough outline of the image but that is labor intensive and not very accurate.

Is there a way to automatically convert a image to a polygon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use GDAL tool inside QGIS. Its free and it works fine. Install [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) and Gdaltools and you'll have a set of tool for raster/image processing. The one you want would be vectorize (gdal_polygonize).